# How to compare two array of object to check one array element with all values of other array?

Tags: java

I need to compare  two array of object to check one array element with all values of other array. If I perform this way it shows NULL point exception at if statement.

```
package unlcomp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class relation {
    int rcount=0;
    int r1count=0;
    public String[] rel=new String[100];
    relation rm[]=new relation[100];
    relation rm1[]=new relation[100];
    public String[] UW1=new String[1000];


    public relation[] hash(String[] s,String[] s1,int rcount) {
        for(int i=1;i<=rcount;i++) {
            rm[i]=new relation();
            rm[i].rel[i]=s[i];
            rm[i].UW1[i]=s1[i];
        }
        return rm;

        // System.out.println(rcount);
    }

    public relation[] hash1(String[] s,String[] s1,int r1count) {
        for(int i=1;i<=r1count;i++) {
            rm1[i]=new relation();
            rm1[i].rel[i]=s[i];
            rm1[i].UW1[i]=s1[i];
        }
        return rm1;
    }

    public void compare() {
        relation r[]= rm;
        relation r1[]=rm1;

        for(int i=1;i<r.length;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<r1.length;j++) {
                if(r1[i].rel[i].equals(r[j].rel[j])) {
                    System.out.println("true");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("false");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I need to call this compare method from another class name.

This is the class that call the above functions..

```
package unlcomp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Unlcomp {
    public   String[]rel;
    public   String[]  UW1;
    public   String[]  UW2=new String[100];
    public   String[] att1=new String[100];
    public   String[] att2=new String[100];
    int i=0;

    public String[] store=new String[500];
    String pattern2="[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\(]";

    //String pattern = "[(]+[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\(.,]";
    String pattern = "[(]+[-a-z0-9R:_]+[(]+[-a-z0-9R:_-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[)]+[\\.\\,\\:]";
    String patterna = "[(]+[-a-z0-9R:_]+[(]+[-a-z0-9R:_-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[)]+[\\,]";
    //String pattern1="[,]+[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\(.]";
    String pattern1="[,]+[-a-z0-9R:_]+[(]+[-a-z0-9R_,>-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[)]+[\\)\\.]";
    //String pattern1a="[,]+[-a-z0-9R:_]+[(]+[-a-z0-9R_,>-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[)]+[\\.]";
    String pattern3="[\\)]+[\\.@]+[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\ ,]";
    String pattern4="[\\)]+[\\.@]+[-a-z0-9R:._-`&=*'`~&+,:;=?@#'<>.^*%!-\"\\+[\\s]]+[\\ )]";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    //Pattern ra = Pattern.compile(patterna);
    Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
    //Pattern r1a = Pattern.compile(pattern1a);
    Pattern r2 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
    Pattern r3 = Pattern.compile(pattern3);
    Pattern r4 = Pattern.compile(pattern4);

    String line;
    relation obj=new relation();
    private int rcount=0;

    public  void preprocess(String pathf1,String pathf2) throws Exception {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(pathf1));
            scanner.useDelimiter("###"); 
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File(pathf2));
            scanner1.useDelimiter("###"); 
            //BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathf2));
            if( scanner.hasNext()) {
                if(scanner1.hasNext())
                    extract(scanner.next());
                obj.hash(rel,UW1,rcount);
                extract(scanner1.next());
                obj.hash1(rel,UW1,rcount);
                obj.compare();
            }
            scanner.close();
            scanner1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void extract(String line) {
        String [] lines=line.split("\n"); 
        System.out.println(line);
        rel=new String[100];
        UW1=new String[100];
        for(String line1: lines ) {
            // rel=null;
            // UW1=null;
            //UW2=null;
            //att1=null;
            //att2=null;

            Matcher m2 = r2.matcher(line1);
            Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(line1);
            Matcher m3 = r3.matcher(line1);
            Matcher m4 = r4.matcher(line1);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line1);

            if( m2.find()) {
                rel[i]=m2.group();
                rel[i]=rel[i].substring(0, rel[i].length()-1).trim();
                rcount++;
                //System.out.println(rel[i]);
            }
            if(m.find()) {
                UW1[i]=m.group();
                UW1[i]=UW1[i].substring(1, UW1[i].length()-1).trim();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Unlcomp u=new Unlcomp();
        String pathsr="E:/M.E/project/test.txt";
        String pathdes="E:/M.E/project/test1.txt";
        relation r=new relation();      

        u.preprocess(pathsr,pathdes);

    }
}
```

This takes the values in `rm` it takes values in the object in array. I checked it using `system.out.println()` statement. I don't no how to return it. This is full coding of this concept, it reads input from the file.

Comment: When asking about an NPE please post the stack trace... Voting to close as is....

Comment: How are you calling `hash()` and `hash1()`, and what `String` arrays are you passing in?

Comment: Where do you add the data to the arrays?

Comment: @Thihara - a stack trace isn't going to tell us anything new.  She has already told us which line gives the exception.

Comment: My guess is that you have a null in the array somewhere.

Comment: How can you create an array of a class X objects in the same class X?

Comment: @dARKpRINCE There's no reason why she can't.

Comment: paste the full code plz...

Comment: better show us method where you are calling hash, hash1

Comment: @DavidWallace It's my personal belief that a stack-trace in a situation like this can give a diagnostic advantage. It can at the very least tell which variable is responsible, plus it also confirms that OPs assumption is correct about where the NPE is popping up... Of course this is just my personal belief so I may be wrong..

Comment: Check my answer, I THINK I may have solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

The if statement can only cast a nullpointer if the place in the array is Null else the method looks fine except you are only looking at one place in the sub array `r1[i].rel[i]`

```
             if(r1[i].rel[i].equals(r[j].rel[j]))
             {
                 System.out.println("true");
             }
             else
             {
                System.out.println("false");
```

Also lose the initialization of non static or final variables

```
public class relation {
int rcount;
int r1count;
public String[] rel;
relation rm[];
relation rm1[];
public String[] UW1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely with nulls.

Either r1 or r1[i] or r1[i].rel[i] or r[j] might be null.

Check for nulls before you compare.

Comment: how to check null values ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 relation rm[];
 relation rm1[];

public relation[] hash(String[] s,String[] s1,int rcount)
{
   rm = new relation[rcount];
   rm1 = new relation[rcount];

    ...
}

// Do the same for hash1
```

In your code, unless `rcount` is `100`, there will be `null` indices if `rcount` is less than 100 and you would get an `IndexOutOfBounds` if `rcount` is greater than 100.
These two things will occur because you declare your arrays as having 100 indices.

Also, here FYI

```
(r1[i].rel[i].equals(r[j].rel[j]))
```

You are actually comparing whether or not the `Objects` refer to the same `Object reference`, not that that are actually `==`.  I don't know if this affects your desired output or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not updated you calling method how you are populating your `relation[]` of `rm` and `rm1` and in `compare` method, two loop condtion end point is length, as you have defined the length as `100` for

```
public String[] rel = new String[100];
relation rm[] = new relation[100];
```

so loop will be itrated for 100 times and in `if (r1[i].rel[i].equals(r[j].rel[j])) {`

```
r1[i].rel[i] , here r1[i]
```

is null for the index when you have not intilized with the object in that position of the array,

and any operation you are trying to do on `null` is null.rel[i] will turn into `NPE`,

You need to take care for the

```
public String[] rel = new String[100];
    relation rm[] = new relation[100];
```

ensure you have element in all the poistion.

```
extract(scanner.next());
obj.hash(rel,UW1,rcount);
```

in your `preprocess` method, are you sure always you are passing `rCount` as 100, if not then in `hash` method you don't have all element in the array of relation object. one way to check null before making comparison like

```
if ( r1[i] != null && r[j] != null && r1[i].rel[i].equals(r[j].rel[j]))
```